# Zotero cannot retrieve metadata from PDF

Tags: pdf, metadata, zotero

When I right click on a PDF and select `retrieve metadata for pdf` the pop up window appears but the auto indexing fails and returns `could not read text from pdf`. This happens even for PDFs for which I know the auto indexing works. I would greatly appreciate any help to solve this issue.

## Further information

### Software versions

**pdftotext**: version 3.02.
**pdfinfo**: version 3.02.
**Ubuntu**: 14.04 LTS.
**Zotero**: standalone version 4.0.23.

### Installation of Zotero

I installed Zotero following the instructions detailed [here](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-zotero-standalone-app-4-0-22-on-ubuntu-14-10-ubuntu-14-04-ubuntu-12-04-and-derivative-systems/).

Answer (score 1):

Solved by deleting pdftotext and pdfinfo from the zotero directory and re-installing them.