# Zotero indexing

Tags: pdf, metadata, indexing, zotero

On 14.04 Zotero installation version 4.0.26, Zotero doesn't let me index PDF files ('Retrieve metadata for PDF'). It returns: `Could not read text from PDF.`

I updated Zotero and checked if it has updated pdftotext & pdfinfo installed and it did, however, it was placed in a different directory (`/usr/bin`), not in Zotero directory (`/opt/Zotero`).

To overcome this problem, I moved them to Zotero directory, thinking, this might solve the issue, but the same error message appeared.

Now, having that said, I am aware that pdftotext and pdfinfo might come preinstalled with Ubuntu installation and that their reninstallation might fix the issue (as pointed out at [Zotero cannot retrieve metadata from PDF](https://askubuntu.com/questions/574980/zotero-retrieve-metadata-for-pdf-is-not-working)). Although, where exactly should I put place them and how exactly are they uninstalled and reinstaled? I think just deleting the files won't do the trick.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, now I understand!...solution was to remove all the pdftotext & pdfinfo files in Zotero directory and re-install them from inside of Preferences/Search option in Zotero Standalone. Now indexing from metadata works. Hope this help anyone in need. Cheers!

Comment: Heads up for everyone: once you remove the files, you have to **restart Zotero** before re-installing them inside the Preferences/Search option. Otherwise Zotero thinks they are still available.